# Accessing different vpn networks about vpn lan connection

Tags: vpn, lan, fritzbox

I have 3 locations with indipendent networks. Locations A, B, C. Each location accessing the internet about a fritzbox (different types).

Already I connected A to B and B to C. Now i am trying to reach C from A about B, but without connecting C directly to A.

I already managed it to put net C in accesslist for vpn config in A.
But it is not working.

Is it generlly possible to do that and if yes, must I do further config to get it working?

Comment: It is possible, but I'll need a bit more precisions to really help you. What is your VPN solution? Which of your locations (A, B or C) has the/a VPN server?

Comment: VPN solution is AVM Fritzbox built in IPsec xauth psk. On all locations I have a fritzbox and vpn is lan to lan. So no extra ip is used for "client" fritzbox in guest network. So I have no dedicated vpn server.